# Calculating weighted averages using loops in a data frame

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a large dataframe with many values and one weight. I would like to calculate the weighted average of many variables using this one weight, and I'm trying to find an efficient code for doing this.

As an example, say I have the following dataframe:

```
library(stringi)

set.seed(200)

df <- cbind.data.frame(id = stri_rand_strings(6, 3, pattern = "[A-Za-z0-9]"),
                        year = 2005 ,
                        australia = runif(6, min=0, max=100) ,
                        austria = runif(6, min=0, max=100) ,
                        weight = runif(6, min=0, max=100) )
```

giving

```
   id year australia   austria   weight
1 Xaa 2005 92.217757 31.942681 26.37486
2 gfq 2005 64.632962 26.532429 16.60537
3 i5W 2005 46.036069 71.736956 48.30747
4 ESe 2005  9.874701 38.033536 32.57277
5 9eN 2005 20.659381  3.062094 92.53639
6 JZ8 2005 92.233983 52.141938 56.05588
```

I would like to calculate the weighted average of each variable with the country names with the weight. I could calculate this of course using :

```
weighted.mean(df$australia , df$weight)
weighted.mean(df$austria , df$weight)
```

but this would be extremely cumbersome when having over 30 variables of the `value` type. Is there a way to automatize this?

Comment: Do you the specific columns? Is there a way to index them? ie `df[, 3:4]` for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
mycols <- c("australia", "austria")
df %>%
#   mutate(across(mycols, list(wavg = ~ weighted.mean(., weight))))
   id year australia austria weight australia_wavg austria_wavg
# 1 Xaa 2005   92.2178 31.9427 26.375         48.203       33.744
# 2 gfq 2005   64.6330 26.5324 16.605         48.203       33.744
# 3 i5W 2005   46.0361 71.7370 48.307         48.203       33.744
# 4 ESe 2005    9.8747 38.0335 32.573         48.203       33.744
# 5 9eN 2005   20.6594  3.0621 92.536         48.203       33.744
# 6 JZ8 2005   92.2340 52.1419 56.056         48.203       33.744
```

or summarizing it with

```r
df %>%
  summarize(across(mycols, list(wavg = ~ weighted.mean(., weight))))
#   australia_wavg austria_wavg
# 1         48.203       33.744
```

### base R

```r
mycols <- c("australia", "austria")
lapply(subset(df, select = mycols), weighted.mean, df$weight)
# $australia
# [1] 48.203
# $austria
# [1] 33.744
```

Comment: I apologise, I forgot to mention that the names of each variable are country names

Comment: Your code would not work if the variable names have a different pattern

Comment: Do you not know the columns' names beforehand? If you do, then your question is moot, use `dplyr::one_of` in lieu of `starts_with`, or `select=c(myvars)` in base R.

Comment: See my edit, it is not using your `value*` names anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You could use any of the following:

```
> colSums(df[, 3:4] * prop.table(df[, 'weight']))
australia   austria
 48.20293  33.74373 

> sapply(df[, 3:4], weighted.mean, df[, 'weight'])
australia   austria 
 48.20293  33.74373
```